# I am stuck on this step of starting up an ubuntu virtualmachine using virtualbox. Please help

Tags: virtualbox

I am stuck on this step of starting up an ubuntu virtualmachine using virtualbox. Please help
[image: Help]

Answer (score 0):

The error message on top may be related to a wrong graphics adapter in your VirtualBox settings.
You may try some different settings for the adapter and see what happens.